# EF 6 performance while updating multiple records with different values in same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table , whose values are updated conditional basis, and when I am calling

```
db.SaveChanges()
```

there is a huge performance drop.

I am also setting properties

```
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;                  
db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

still results are not as expected.

Edit 1:

```
using(var db= new MyEntities())
{
  db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;                  
  db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

 foreach(var acc in myacclist)
 {
    //will update my account objects here
 }
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: you might want to share the surrounding code with us. SaveChanges() does a lot of things, whereas the performance of this mostly depends on the internal context state and connection handling.

Comment: Myacclist has 100000 items?

Comment: It will have more than 10000 accounts and at times more than 50k

Comment: Usually EF is not really good when it comes to performance

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way you will be able to have good performance with Entity Framework and SaveChanges.

SaveChange makes a database round-trip for every record update. So if you currently have 10,000 accounts, 10k database round-trip is performed.

Setting AutoDetectChangesEnabled and ValidateOnSaveEnabled is usually a very bad idea and will not really improve the performance since it the number of database round-trip the real issue.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library allows to dramatically improve performance by performing:

- BulkSaveChanges
- BulkInsert
- BulkUpdate
- BulkDelete
- BulkMerge

Example:

```
using(var db= new MyEntities())
{
    foreach(var acc in myacclist)
    {
        //will update my account objects here
    }

    db.BulkSaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building a Update query in string builder and saving it for every 1k records improved my performance

```
using (var db = new MyEntities())
{
     StringBuilder finalquery = new StringBuilder();
     int i = 0;
     foreach (var acc in myacclist)
     {
       i++;
       //will update my account objects here
       finalquery.Append(stmnt);
       if (1 % 1000 = 0) { db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(finalquery.ToString()); }
      }

      db.SaveChanges();
 }
```